# Chained payment with paypal pro

Tags: php, paypal

I need to implement chained payment with paypal pro. Can I do it as I can do in adaptive payments? Means doing payments to multiple receivers from one payer who does not have a PayPal account and can pay from his/her credit card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to do this with Website Payments Pro the same way that you use it for Adaptive Payments.  The only way to split a payment in the Website Payments Pro flow is to process multiple DoDirectPayment API requests.  You would either need to have all of the API credentials for all of the accounts that you are going to be making the API calls on, or you would need to have those accounts grant 3rd party permissions to your API credentials and then just pass over the email address of their PayPal account in the variable `subject`.

Comment: Thanks for your response can you please describe me the second approach which you have suggested.I mean how can other user grant 3rd party permissions to my API credentials and how can i pass their email address to subject.I know it can be very easy to implement but i can understand as i am very new to this field.

Comment: The link https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/791/kw/grant%203rd%20party%20permissions describes what your clients will need to do to grant 3rd party permissions to your API user in their account.  As for passing their email address over, all you need to do is just pass over the additional variable with the rest of your variables and setting it to their email address.  ex: &SUBJECT=test@test.com&........

Comment: thaks a lot,just last bit of question can i use multiple email address(receiver) in subject.if i can please specify what will be the syntax of that.

Comment: I also tried with an api username which is working for paypal pro dodirect payment but when i am using it as api username in "Add New Third Party Permissions" it is giving error "Please enter valid API username."

Comment: I also need to specify that i do not get any check boxes in "Add New Third Party Permissions" page

Comment: You would not be able to add multiple email addresses in the subject variable.  As for your credentials, make sure you are not trying to add it to the account you created it from.  Also make sure that you use a live API user name for live accounts, and a sandbox API username for sandbox accounts.  If you still receive an error, can you provide me witht he API user name you are tyring to add and let me know if you are doing this on live or sandbox and I will try to test it from my end.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions i have followed those but still getting an error "Please enter valid API username." when i am loging with The credentials "username:prabir.m@isisdsn.net;password:prabir123" and tring to grant 3rd party permissions to account with the following credentials "Username:sujoybhowmick68@yahoo.in;password:sujoy123" i am using "sujoybhowmick68-facilitator_api1.yahoo.in" as api username for that.both the a/c are sandbox a/c and you can login with described credential to test.please reply ASAP.

Comment: Actually i am developing some webservices for the ios.and i have some situation when app user can cancel a ride and i have to make a background payment from user a/c to driver and admin's a/c. though i will have the card info of user who will pay i can't redirect him/her to any other page,"the payment have to be made from back end" from  webservice.One imp point i do need to make chained payment but i cant get api_info of each driver rather i can get it for admin.Please help me.